# Analysis of $(y-x)^2 =x^3 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was doing some tasks in integral application and came across this one:

> Calculate the surface area bounded by $(y-x)^2 = x^3$ and line $x=2$

I started doing this the usual way, when I realized that this relation cannot be written in explicit form so I cannot really draw it. While the task of calculating the surface area might prove difficult in itself, The bigger problem here (at least for me) seems to be the analysis ( drawing, finding minima and maxima ).

What I've managed so far is to find the zeros $x=0, x=1$ and to notice that no $x<0$ satisfies this relation.

How do I go about finding the minima and maxima? How do I use derivatives to find minima and maxima here?

This is the first time I am doing any kind of 2-variable analysis so the whole idea seems difficult to grasp for me. And imagining how this actually looks in $xy$ plane seems impossible.

I do not need a solution for this task, just some general guidelines on analysing such expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve for $y$, directly: $y=x\pm x^{3/2}$. You need to look at these two branches to understand how the plot goes. The intersection point is $x=0$, so you will end up getting
$$
\int_0^2(x+x^{3/2})-(x-x^{3/2})\,dx.
$$
I don't think there is a very general advice as you are looking for, but maybe someone will contradict me.

Comment: Oh my. I feel very silly at the moment. I really overthought this whole thing, so much that I forgot to actually try to get an explicit form.

Answer (score 0):

For the second bound you want to find the value of $y$ depending of the value of $x$ : $$(y-x)^2 = x^3 \Rightarrow y^2-2xy+(4-x^3)=0$$

So if you solve as a polynom in $y$, you will be able to bound the $dy$ part of you integral (**important** :the bounds will depend of $x$). So you will obtain something like this :

$$\int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)}\int_{0}^1f(x,y)dxdy$$